# Determine if an open application is minimized or maximized with batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, script

I am running a batch script to display a schedule on a machine HMI, my script displays the schedule in notepad and if the schedule has been updated I am deleting the current file and displaying the new schedule maximized for the operator to see. I have a scheduled task running every minute to check certain conditions

Does the schedule exist Exists - check to see if there is a newer version - if newer version, delete old schedule from HMI and open new schedule maximized - if exists and there is not a newer version then check if schedule is open on the HMI - reopen schedule minimized if it has been closed. Does not exist - Copy schedule from the network and open schedule maximized on the HMI
I want to make sure the operator sees the schedule if it has changed, if the schedule is minimized I will assume they have looked at it, but if another application stole focus from the schedule I would like to be able to determine if the schedule is still maximized in the background.

The Question: Is there a script I could use to check if the window has been minimized (by the operator) or the schedule (notepad app) is still maximized in the background but another application stole focus and if it is still maximized in background bring it back to main focus?

The HMI's are touchscreens and I don't know if by selecting the schedule (notepad app) on the windows desktop toolbar qualifies as being minimized like actually minimizing the app with the controls in the upper right corner?

Here's the main script, I have two aditional scripts that are called to either open schedule min or max based on some additional criteria.

```
@ECHO off
 
    IF NOT EXIST "c:\temp\Builder Schedule"\schedule.txt GOTO one

    GOTO two

:one

    TASKKill /IM notepad.exe
    TASKKill /IM notepad.exe
    TASKKill /IM notepad.exe
    TASKKill /IM notepad.exe
    TASKKill /F /FI "USERNAME eq NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /IM notepad.exe

    ROBOCOPY "\\global\americas\data\ceng\shared\InfinityQS\Tire Assembly\2nd Stage Builder Checks\Servicer Schedule"\ 3DR* /Z /FFT "C:\temp\Builder Schedule"\  /LOG:"c:\temp\Builder Schedule\log"\log.log

TIMEOUT /T 2

    REN "c:\temp\Builder Schedule"\3DR.txt schedule.txt

    call "c:\temp\Builder Schedule\scripts"\UpdateBuilderSchedule.bat

    GOTO four

:two    
    ROBOCOPY "\\global\americas\data\ceng\shared\InfinityQS\Tire Assembly\2nd Stage Builder Checks\Servicer Schedule"\ 3DR* /Z /FFT "c:\temp\Builder Schedule"\  /LOG:"c:\temp\Builder Schedule\log"\log.log

    FC "c:\temp\Builder Schedule"\3DR.txt "c:\temp\Builder Schedule"\schedule.txt /B

    echo %errorlevel%

    if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 goto three

    GoTo end

:three


    TASKKill /IM notepad.exe
    TASKKill /IM notepad.exe
    TASKKill /IM notepad.exe
    TASKKill /IM notepad.exe
    TASKKill /F /FI "USERNAME eq NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /IM notepad.exe

TIMEOUT /T 2

    del "c:\temp\Builder Schedule"\schedule.txt /F /Q


    REN "c:\temp\Builder Schedule"\3DR.txt schedule.txt
TIMEOUT /T 1
    
    call "c:\temp\Builder Schedule\scripts"\UpdateBuilderSchedule.bat
    
    GoTo four

:end

QPROCESS "notepad.exe">NUL

echo %errorlevel%

IF %errorlevel% EQU 0 goto four

call "c:\temp\Builder Schedule\scripts"\Minimized.bat

:four
del "c:\temp\Builder Schedule"\3DRtemp.txt /F /Q
del "c:\temp\Builder Schedule"\*.tmp /F /Q
exit
```

Comment: If condition A run code from bat X (start notepad) minimized, else it condition A run bat Y start (notepad) maximized. Why not use one bat for run each condition?

Comment: I do have a call for each of those 2 conditions. "UpdateBuilderSchedule.bat" (maximized window) and "Minimized.bat" (minimized window)

Comment: Bat I can share with you the codes in C# and compiled version I’ve work for get the kind of task for you. Let me know if you can test it and check if this suggest let help you. This intent to use: `Status file_name.eXtencion` And result will be: `True`, `False` or `File not open!`